# Handling a tab seperated file (csv) with open csv?

Tags: java, opencsv

I've tried to create my reader like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("ping10102012.csv"), '\t');

int i=0;
while ( (nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null){
    System.out.println(nextLine[i]); // Debug only
}
```

And I'm having some issues with stuff.   I'm only getting the first(column) values from my csv, and they're outputting pretty weird.

output:

```
I  D
2  7  2  2  2
2  4  6  9  4
...more like this
```

The columns are:

UnitId

Attempts

ACPower

etc. etc.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Thanks for any help!` -> We cannot help without a question.. and some more explanation..

Comment: @ Damien.Bell : Your file may not be tab separated?  Please show actual file and actual code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing first column only as all the time as `i=0` and there is no change in value assigned to `i`.

Try this:

```
         while ( (nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null){
            for(String value: nextLine){
               System.out.println(value); // Debug only
            }
        }
```

Comment: Huge derp moment on that one.   I'm still having a small issue where I'm getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.   I'm not entirely sure why that's happening

Comment: Updated the answer to use `for` loop to print the column values. Its check the length internally. Hope that helps.